# How to load external CSS files dynamically in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to do a lazy loading of CSS files which would be loaded on demand?

For example I have dummy article component and when I try to load that article from API, I also get information that there is a CSS file linked with this object and I need to somehow import it to this component or place it globally. Right now I don't take care about redundancy (I will solve it later).

But I cannot find any information about such logic.

Thanks for any proposed solutions or correction of my workflow

Comment: It doesn't exist in AngularJS but you can easily add a directive or a few lines of code that adds the style to the DOM. It will be hard to isolate it only to your component, but maybe it won't influence the rest of your app.

Comment: Ok, thank you. So now I'm sure there is no native way.

Comment: Not is clear to me the question! You're asking how to implement a lazy loader until the styles are completed? Something like this https://github.com/NetanelBasal/ngx-content-loader

Comment: @JonathanBrizio By lazy loading I ment any time during application lifetime. I know I can reference external styles prior render, if I would know the url, but that is not the case, because styles or other external resources will be loaded on demand when for example loaded object from API will contain them or not.